# Convert an Axios promise to a regular JSON array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios, es6-promise

I'm trying to return data from a function, but it's giving me issues.

I need this function to return JSON, but it's returning a promise.

Here is the function:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const fetchData = async () => {
  const result = await axios(
    'https://localhost:44376/api/parts',
  );
  return JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
};

export default fetchData;
```

It's throwing this error when I try to use the returned data:

> Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function

When I write out to the console, here is what I see:

```
data from machineParts API call:

Promise {<pending>}
 [[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
    [[PromiseValue]]: {"data": [ { "id": 5, "title": "Steel Rods", "partId": 39482  etc...
```

But here is what I need it to return:

```
data from machineParts API call: (7) [ {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}]

0:
   id: 5
   title: "Steel Rods"
   partId: 39482

1:
   id: 23
   title: "Honed Cylinder head"
   partId: 23412
```

etc...

Is there anyway to convert a promise to a JSON array?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get response from axios with await/async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49661209/get-response-from-axios-with-await-async)

Comment: response.data already has the data you want, an array or on object depending on the server response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just want to call `.then()` after you calling `fetchData` function:

```js
// fetchData.js
import axios from "axios";

const fetchData = async () => {
  const result = await axios(
    'https://localhost:44376/api/parts',
  );
  // return the result
  return result;
};

export default fetchData;
```

Now import it inside your component like so:

```js
// App.js 
import fetchData from './fetchData' // fetchData path

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([])

  React.useEffect(() => {

   fetchData().then(res => {
     setData(res.data)
   })
  },[])

  return (
    <div>
      <pre>
        <code> {JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)} </code>
      </pre>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

**See [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-ramanujan-cu0jc) example.**

Comment: Thanks, my current App.js is setup to use the data like this: const [data, setData] = React.useState(() => fetchData())

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell You better initially set usestate to an empty array `useState([ ])` then update it later with `useEffect` in case your data is not ready yet, or some server fail happened. Please see the sandbox example in the answer.

Comment: Ok thanks, I see your sandbox works.   When I use it, I get 'undefined'. So I put a 'console.log('function: ', result.data);' just before the 'return' statement, inside the function and it returns all the data I am looking for. And I put a 'console.log("App.js: ", data);' and it just returns 'undefined'.

Comment: Have you called `.then()` after `fetchData()`? please note that fetchData function is returning a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that you still need to resolve.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Can you make a sandbox with your code? you can use some dummy API's like [reqres](https://reqres.in/) or [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)

Answer (score 3):

`async` and `await` are just a different syntax for handling promises, the 'await' more or less works the same as chaining a `.then` on the call to `axios`. Something like this should work in the module:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get('https://localhost:44376/api/parts');
  return response.data;
};
```

Because `fetchData()` is an `async` function, it will return a `Promise`, so the calling code will either have to `await` the result or use `.then` syntax to access the resulting data.

Comment: But I'm using async and await

Comment: I edited my answer to use async/await. Best of luck getting this resolved.

Comment: Would I need to use .then to get rid of the returned promise?

Comment: You could use a .then from the code that calls fetchData, or you could await the call to fetchData. Both could work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the console you shared, the line starting with `data from machineParts API call:`. The array is nested under a `data` prop.

You're also `JSON.stringify`ing the result, which would make it a string and no longer a string or object. That is why you are seeing the `data.map is not a function` error, because `string` doesn't have a prototype method named `map`.

To fix, change `return JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);` to `return result.data;`.

Comment: I tried that and still see all the promise stuff and I still get the same error