# How to adjust the order of events occurring in async Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, axios

I am working on authentication for my react native app.

The problem I am having is that the signInUser function seems to be executing in the wrong order. I want the signIn function to fully execute before moving on.

However, that doesn't seem to be happening as I am getting this response in my console, with the "undefined" coming from console.log(response) in the SignInScreen.

Here is the **console**:

```
undefined
16d0707a3508a9b43b8c36c8574ca73d8b4b26af
```

I have this function in the **SignInScreen.js**

```
import { signIn } from "../services/authService";
import { useAuthDispatch } from "../contexts/authContext";

const SignInScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const dispatch = useAuthDispatch();
  const [signInLoading, setSignInLoading] = useState(false);

  const signInUser = async (values) => {
    const { email, password } = values;
    setSignInLoading(true);

    signIn(email, password)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        dispatch({
          type: "SIGN_IN",
          token: response,
        });
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      })
      .finally(() => setSignInLoading(false));
  };
```

And this is my **authService.js**:

```
import axios from "axios";

const signIn = async (email, password) => {
  axios
    .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/", {
      username: email,
      email: email,
      password: password,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data.key);
      return response.data.key;
    })

    .catch((error) => {
      return error;
    });
};
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just need to put `return` in front of `axios.post`. If you don't do that, you can't get any data out. You also are using `async` there, but not `await`, so no real reason to use `async`. However, `async` functions automatically return promises, which you can await, but if you don't return the promise from `axios`, you can't get the data out.

Comment: Thank you for this! I also found a guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49661209/get-response-from-axios-with-await-async/49661388