# axios API - wait for response

Tags: javascript

I'am sending data to server with axios library

the query is working, but i'am not able to wait the answer of axios

```
import axios from '../helper/axiosAPI'

 /** data send to axios */
 let formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('file',this.file);

 /**Axios query */
 try{
    axios.post(formData)  
    .then(res=> console.log('result : ' + res)) // no data recieve              
  }
  catch(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
```

here my post request (axiosAPI file):

```
axios = require('axios').default;
const uri = process.env.VUE_APP_URI;
const endPoint = 'professional/upload'

 exports.post = async (formData) =>{
 axios({
    method:'post',
    url:uri + endPoint,
    data:formData,
    headers:{
        "Content-Type": "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
    }
})
.then(response => {   
    console.log('axios : ' + response) // response is recieved    
    return response.data })
.catch(err => console.log(`Erreur AXIOS API : + ${err}`));
```

}

my Axios query work well and data is post to server.
But i am not succed to wait the reponse from the server.

console.log('result : ' + res)=> (res is undefined -> not waiting for axios response)

console.log('axios : ' + response)   =>(response is recieve from server)

It will be very nice if you help me to find a solution to wait axios result

thanks a lot

Comment: Your problem is the `return response.data`. It is not returning the value to the `post` function but to the `then` lambda function. You could instead use either Promise resolve syntax or full async await syntax. This mix and match here is confusing and causing unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `await` with axios:

Like this:

```
try
{
    let res = await axios.post(formData);
    console.log('result : ' + res); // no data received
}
catch(err)
{
    console.log(err);
}
```

and this:

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
const uri = process.env.VUE_APP_URI;
const endPoint = 'professional/upload';

exports.post = async (formData) =>{
    try
    {
        let response = await axios(
            {
                method: 'post',
                url: uri + endPoint,
                data: formData,
                headers:
                {
                    "Content-Type": "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
                }
            }
        );

        console.log('axios : ' + response); // response is received    
        return response.data;
    }
    catch (err) 
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

See also:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49661388/194717

https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Comment: This is the correct way of using axios, instead of using promises async/await is a lot clearer in what it does.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It's work perfectly. I think that need some training with async - await ans promise....

Answer (score 0):

Since your handle is async so you need to put await before axios calling.

```
exports.post = async (formData) =>{
 return await axios({
    method:'post',
    url:uri + endPoint,
    data:formData,
    headers:{
        "Content-Type": "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
    }
})
```

Comment: That is correct but not the cause of the issue here.